# Set Query to set a time field to the last time another field boolean value changed

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table which contains history of changes done to user entity. I’ve added a new field called started_at to the user and I want to write a Mysql query to set this field for the users who has been promoted, to the last time this happened, and for the users who doesn’t have this scenario, the their created_at time.

Table  history:

| updated_at | promoted | uuid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-11-12 14:42:01 | 1 | x |
| 2023-11-10 14:42:01 | 1 | x |
| 2023-11-05 14:42:01 | 0 | x |
| 2023-11-04 14:42:01 | 0 | x |
| 2023-11-03 14:42:01 | 1 | x |
| 2023-11-02 14:42:01 | 1 | x |
| 2023-11-01 14:42:01 | 0 | x |

Table users:

| uuid | promoted | started_at | created_at | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | 1 | 2023-11-10 14:42:01 | 2022-11-10 14:42:01 | ... |

Comment: You have added a new _column_, not a field.

Comment: There's only one user, x. I'd recommend sample data including both promoted and never promoted users.

Answer (score 0):

The query below finds the most previous promotion date (or `null` if it exists), and then performs a `join` of the original `history` table back onto the results:

```
select t.uuid, h.promoted, coalesce(t.dt, t.cdt), t.cdt from (select h.uuid, 
       max(case when h.promoted = 1 then h.updated_at end) dt, min(h.updated_at) cdt 
  from history h group by h.uuid) t
join history h on h.updated_at = coalesce(t.dt, t.cdt)
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FK4QGzWR)